# VI Quality dataset in MODIS image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, ndvi, evi

While importing NDVI dataset in ArcGIS should we also import the **VI_Quality** dataset ?

If yes then how should we handle it ?

and, if not, then for what it is there ?